# How should I save user settings from a uitable selection?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

I have a table view where the user can select multiple rows. I would like to save the user's selections. Is NSUserDefaults the best way to handle this? There are only a few selections the user can make. One of them is where they can select and save several categories that they would like to have appear in their search results in another table view.

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSObject *tempSelectedObject = [yourTableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSMutableArray *yourSelectedArray;
    [yourSelectedArray addObject:tempSelectedList];

    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

In this case any row of your table that has selected will remove from the list and will store in `yourSelectedArray`. you can do what ever you want with that later. if you want to save it in file or so you can use `NSDictionary` beside `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: at the moment when I select more than one table row I get a "*** -[NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]: Attempt to insert non-property value '(
    "<NSIndexPath 0xa6eb3a0> 2 indexes [0, 3]"
)' of class '__NSArrayM'.  Note that dictionaries and arrays in property lists must also contain only property values.

Answer (score 1):

May be store your data in `NSDictionary` and then store that in `NSUserDefaults`.